# getting error while simulating LiH using VQE

Tags: quantum-algorithms, simulation, vqe

I wrote code again using updated qiskit nature libraries but I am facing error , I need help to finding solution so that we can run this code on latest version of qiskit.

I am attaching code below......

import numpy as np

## Importing standard Qiskit libraries

from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, transpile, Aer, IBMQ
from qiskit.tools.jupyter import *
from qiskit.visualization import *
from ibm_quantum_widgets import *
from qiskit.providers.aer import QasmSimulator

## Loading your IBM Quantum account(s)

provider = IBMQ.load_account()
:219: RuntimeWarning: scipy._lib.messagestream.MessageStream size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 56 from C header, got 64 from PyObject
In [3]:
from qiskit.algorithms import VQE
from qiskit_nature.second_q.algorithms import (GroundStateEigensolver,
NumPyMinimumEigensolverFactory)
from qiskit_nature.second_q.drivers import PySCFDriver
from qiskit_nature.second_q.formats.molecule_info import MoleculeInfo
from qiskit_nature.second_q.transformers import FreezeCoreTransformer
from qiskit_nature.second_q.mappers import ParityMapper, QubitConverter, JordanWignerMapper

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from qiskit_nature.second_q.circuit.library import UCCSD, HartreeFock
from qiskit.circuit.library import EfficientSU2
from qiskit.algorithms.optimizers import COBYLA, SPSA, SLSQP
from qiskit.opflow import TwoQubitReduction
from qiskit import BasicAer, Aer
from qiskit.utils import QuantumInstance
from qiskit.utils.mitigation import CompleteMeasFitter
from qiskit.providers.aer.noise import NoiseModel
:219: RuntimeWarning: scipy._lib.messagestream.MessageStream size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 56 from C header, got 64 from PyObject
In [4]:
def get_qubit_op(dist):
# Define Molecule
molecule = MoleculeInfo(
# Coordinates in Angstrom
["Li", "H"], [(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (dist, 0.0, 0.0)],
multiplicity=1,  # = 2*spin + 1
charge=0,
)

```
driver = PySCFDriver.from_molecule(molecule, basis="sto3g")

# Get properties
properties = driver.run()
num_particles = properties.num_particles
num_spatial_orbitals = properties.num_spatial_orbitals

# Define Problem, Use freeze core approximation, remove orbitals.

transformer = FreezeCoreTransformer(freeze_core=True,remove_orbitals=[-3,-2])
problem = transformer.transform(properties)

num_spatial_orbitals = problem.num_spatial_orbitals
num_particles = problem.num_particles

hamiltonian = problem.hamiltonian.second_q_op()
# Do two qubit reduction
converter = QubitConverter(JordanWignerMapper())
reducer = TwoQubitReduction(num_particles)
qubit_op = converter.convert(hamiltonian)
qubit_op = reducer.convert(qubit_op)

return qubit_op, num_particles, num_spatial_orbitals, problem, converter
```

In [5]:
def exact_solver(problem, converter):
solver = NumPyMinimumEigensolverFactory()
calc = GroundStateEigensolver(converter, solver)
result = calc.solve(problem)
return result

backend = BasicAer.get_backend("statevector_simulator")
distances = np.arange(0.5, 4.0, 0.2)
exact_energies = []
vqe_energies = []
optimizer = SLSQP(maxiter=5)
for dist in distances:
(qubit_op, num_particles, num_spatial_orbitals,
problem, converter) = get_qubit_op(dist)
result = exact_solver(problem,converter)
exact_energies.append(result.total_energies[0].real)

```
var_form = UCCSD()
var_form.num_particles = num_particles
var_form.num_spatial_orbitals = (num_spatial_orbitals)
var_form.qubit_converter = converter
init_state = HartreeFock()
init_state.num_particles = num_particles
init_state.num_spatial_orbitals = (num_spatial_orbitals)
init_state.qubit_converter = converter

var_form.initial_state=init_state

vqe = VQE(var_form, optimizer, quantum_instance=backend)
vqe_calc = vqe.compute_minimum_eigenvalue(qubit_op)
vqe_result = problem.interpret(vqe_calc).total_energies[0].real
vqe_energies.append(vqe_result)
print(f"Interatomic Distance: {np.round(dist, 2)}",
      f"VQE Result: {vqe_result:.5f}",
      f"Exact Energy: {exact_energies[-1]:.5f}")
```

print("All energies have been calculated")
Traceback (most recent call last):
Input In [5] in <cell line: 12>
vqe_calc = vqe.compute_minimum_eigenvalue(qubit_op)
File /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qiskit/algorithms/minimum_eigen_solvers/vqe.py:496 in compute_minimum_eigenvalue
self._check_operator_ansatz(operator)
File /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qiskit/algorithms/minimum_eigen_solvers/vqe.py:331 in _check_operator_ansatz
raise AlgorithmError(
AlgorithmError: 'The number of qubits of the ansatz does not match the operator, and the ansatz does not allow setting the number of qubits using `num_qubits`.'

Use %tb to get the full traceback.
Search for solution online

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you will run this code then you will know as well what is the problem